# Error exporting Access database table to new database, can't find what should not yet exist

Tags: microsoft-access

How do I export a Microsoft Access database table in to it's own *.accdb database?

When viewing the list of tables on the left column under the "Tables" category I can right-click and export but when I give it a name to save the export like "example.accdb" I get the following error message...

> Microsoft Access can't find the database file 'C:\example.accdb'.

Right...because it doesn't exist, that's why I'm exporting in the first place! To create the table as a separate exported database. Am I attempting to split the table off in to another database containing that table incorrectly or is there another step I missed somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat indirect answer, more of a work-around.

1. I created a new blank database.
2. Right-click on the empty table and choose import.
3. Find the accdb database file that contains the table.
4. When you finish it gave me a list of tables that I could import.
5. Select the table to be imported.
6. Close the new/empty table to delete it.
7. Save and link it to the front end file that you need that table linked to.

Comment: Linked tables have some disadvantages in terms of performance. If you are doing this because of database size limit, it is a temporary solution... but you might want to look into other long term solutions like reviewing how your data is stored and structured, whether you should upgrade to a different platform, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A database must exist FIRST in order to accept the exported table. The export function does not create a database file (as you found out).

Create the database you want the data to go to, when you click `Export` then `Access`, choose <kbd>Browse...</kbd> to select the database when exporting.

[image]

Comment: I've always hated this feature with Microsoft Access. Its been like that at least since Access 2003 if not earlier. If it doesn't exist, I wish Access would create a blank database, then export!